# How to use format specifier within switch in C

Tags: c

I am trying to use format specifier within switch however compiler returns error: expression result unused

```
 const char* text;
 const char* input;
 int i=2;
 input = "orange";

 switch(i){
 case 1:
      text = "%s is color", input;
      break;
 case 2:
      text = "%s is fruit", input;
      break;
 default:
      break;
 }
```

Comment: First, you have to allocate memory for strings like:
    char text[128];
    char input[128];
Then, you could use for example sprinf like this:
    sprintf(text, "%s is color", input);

Comment: It's actually not completely clear what you're trying to achieve. Please tell us what you intend to do with `text`.

Comment: The format specifier functionality is not a language-level thing, it's simply implemented by the `printf()` family of functions. In general in C if you want something "complicated" (such as converting various values to string representations) to happen, you need to call a function that implements that.

Comment: regarding: `text = "%s is color", input;` and similar statements:  This is nonsense.  Your compiler is telling you that.  Strongly suggest using `sprintf()` to format the contents of a char array, then you could assign the address of that array to `input` or `text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) or snprintf.

```
char text[128];
const char* input;
int i=2;
input = "orange";

switch(i){
case 1:
    sprintf(text, "%s is color", input);
    break;
case 2:
    sprintf(text, "%s is fruit", input);
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: For this to make sense, `text` must point at allocated memory and it can't be a `const char*`.

Comment: This it not goint to work, `text` is not initialized and probably that's not what the OP wants

Comment: What about `text`?

Comment: @Lundin Thanks. I spotted it too and was about to fix it.

Comment: text is getting initialised within the switch case, and i need to print it outside it switch case

Answer (score 3):

You probably want somewhing like this:

```
 const char* text;
 const char* input;
 int i=2;
 input = "orange";

 switch(i) {
 case 1:
      text = "%s is color";
      break;
 case 2:
      text = "%s is fruit";
      break;
 default:
      break;
 }

 printf(text, input);
```

Comment: You probably want to assign something to `text` in the `default` case (or omit `default:` and just initialize `text` at the declaration).

Comment: this will cause some compilers, like `gcc` to output a warning message about the security risk of using a variable pointer for the format string, rather than the actual format literal.